# I have a string field in a RDLC report that will not display any value

Tags: reportviewer, reportbuilder

This report is generated from an Access table which has a string value which happens to be a number (purchase order number)  All the other string fields in the table will display except for the PO field which is just blank.   I have looked at the datatypes in the designer and everything is correct.  I have reconfigured all the tableadapters and nothing helps.  I am stumped on this one.  I can build the same report in reportbuilder 3.0 and it works perfectly.

Comment: This was a complex problem that had todo with the dataset.  The string field that was showing up blank in the report also showed up blank when I previewed the data.
The fix was to create a new table in the dataset that was created by dragging and dropping the table on to the designer surface.  This made a copy of the table without all the custom queries I had built in the old table.  I rebuilt all the custom queries and then deleted the old table.  I renamed the table back to the original name and now it sees the data.

Comment: I hope this helps someone down the road.  Stackoverflow is the goto from the right answers